# Accidentally disabled DHCP on repeater, can no longer access settings

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, repeater

Our home recently upgraded to a new Netgear router. Another family member set up the Amped SR10000 repeater but I was having problems with it. In the midst of playing with the settings I had disabled DHCP in the Amped repeater menu, but now I can no longer access the Amped settings via it's supplied IP (192.168.1.204).

I'm quite tech savvy but I'm no networking guru. How can I get back into the repeater settings?

Currently:

- I'm connected (in Windows) to the network repeater.
- I have internet access
- If I try to access the repeater via the IP supplied in the [manual](http://www.ampedwireless.com/docs/usersguide/SR10000_UsersGuide_Rev1.1_English.pdf) I get a webpage in Chrome that says *This webpage is not available: ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED*

Comment: Do a factory reset on it, then set it up again.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of searching I stumbled across a post on the Amped Wireless forums ([link](http://www.forums.ampedwireless.com/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=12))

> If you know the IP address of the range extender, and you have the
>   vanishing menu because you did not know to disable Auto-DNS,  try
>   adding in your HOSTS file an entry like
>
> 192.168.5.220 setup.ampedwireless.com # but use YOUR range extender IP address, not this bogus one
>
> save the HOSTS file, and retry accessing setup.ampedwireless.com.
>   Disable Auto-DNS, then delete this line from HOSTS.
>
> There is a Wikipedia article on "hosts (file)" that will help you find
>   where it is on your OS.

In my case, and as reflected in the manual in the original question, the IP for Amped Wireless **SR10000** is **192.168.1.240**.